# _findfirst and wildcard matching

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to use `_findfirst()` Windows API in C to match file name using wildcards.
If I am passing `????????.txt` then I am expecting it will match all the files in a directory with 8 characters only, but it matches more than that.

Is there any thing wrong with this usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that it is matching on the short name. On windows all files have a long name and a DOS 8.3 short name. Therefore "????????.txt" is effectively the same as "*.txt".

Also on a pedantic note, _findfirst() is not part of the Windows API. Is it part of the Microsoft C run-time library.